# H2 with JPA is ignoring my primary key value

Tags: spring, jpa, h2

I have a code like this:

```
 user.setUserId(6L);
 userRepository.save(user)
```

The user is created but the id is not 6. It is the next id of the sequence.

My entity is decorated as that:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;
```

Question: This is the default behavior of h2 and JPA?
How can I change this?

Thank you.

Comment: You have a `@GeneratedValue` annotation on the field, which means JPA will automatically generate an ID, but you're also trying to set the ID yourself (why?). Those two things conflict - choose one or the other.

Comment: Because it is easier to test some crud operations. For example I can save an entity with id=1 and than search for this entity in the database to retrieve the data and see whether it was saved correctly or not.